# How do I do a "group by" in my .net DataTable

Tags: c#

I would like to implement a sql style group by for the columns in my datatabe is this possible?

c#, .net 2.0

Comment: You could use LINQ to OBJECTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [DataTableExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) extension methods to convert the DataTable to an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, then use the `IEnumerable<T>.GroupBy()` [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx).

```
DataTable tbl = ..

var q = tbl.AsEnumerable().GroupBy( r => r.Field<string>("Company") )
                          .Select( g => new { Company = g.Key, TotalSales = g.Sum( s => s.Field<decimal>("Sales") ) } );
```